# Accessing passed elements in scripts tags inside ejs files

Tags: javascript, node.js, ejs

Basically, I am using javascript to build an app for my university using node.js which requires a google map integration

I passed some items through "/" route to landing page of the website and along with some arrays. Final code looks something like this:

```
LostItem.find({},function(err,allLostItems){
      if(err)
      {
         console.log("Some error while finding the items in items.js")
         req.flash("error","Following error encountered : " + err.message);
         res.redirect("back");
      }
       else{
           // render the results from arrays
           res.render("landing",{foundItems:allLostItems}); 
      }

});
```

However, while accessing it in the landing.ejs file, while using the following code:

```
<script async defer type="text/javascript">
    var locations=[];
    index=0;
    lostItems.forEach(function(item){
    var item_array=[];
     // Some more code ...
</script>
```

I get the error:

> lostItems is not defined

I know that this works:

```
<%lostItems.forEach(function(item){%>
    //some code
 <%)};%>
```

What is the correct way to execute the above code in script tags? I apologize if this question is basic, I am new to javascript, and only beginning to dive deeper into it.

Lost Item Schema is :

```
var lostItemsSchema=new mongoose.Schema({
    item:String,
    details:String,
    specifications:String,
    date:String,
    time:String,
    location: String,
    lat: Number,
    lng: Number,
    author:{
        id:{
            type:mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            ref:"User"
        },
        username:String
    },
    comments:[
        {
            type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            ref:"Comment"
        }
    ]
});
```

Comment: you are confusing server side variables with client side ones

Comment: @AshlishGupta is it `foundItems` or `lostItems`? also, could you post an example of the data in `allFoundItems` please?

Comment: Did it, I have added the lost item schema as well.

Answer (score 2):

You can use:

```
let items = '<%- lostItems %>';
items.forEach(function(item){
  // Some more code ...
}
```

or

```
let items = '<%= lostItems %>';
items.forEach(function(item){
  // Some more code ...
}
```

If it's a JSON, parse it in the client:

```
let items = JSON.parse('<%= lostItems %>');
```

or

```
let items = JSON.parse('<%- lostItems %>');
```

or stringify it in the server:

```
res.render("landing",{ foundItems: JSON.stringify(allLostItems) });
```

Comment: Got this error : SyntaxError: '' string literal contains an unescaped line break

Answer (score 1):

OK, I found the solution to this problem. Using this code on the server side:

```
{lostItems:JSON.stringify( allLostItems)}
```

And using the below code on the client side will fix it.

```
let lostItems= <%-lostItems%>
let foundItems= <%-foundItems%> // similar to above

lostItems.forEach(function(item){
// code here
});
```